# Find text that matches front and back and replace but keep what is in middle

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a lot of legacy code I am going through and in one instance there are hundreds of the same issue.  I need to replace

```
assert( 'isNonEmptyString( $string )' );
//with
assert( isNonEmptyString( $string ) );
//This portion isNonEmptyString( $string ) may be different for each one but 
//I want to keep what is in the middle when I replace it.
```

I have seen other posts somewhat similar and this may be considered a duplicate but I couldn't figure out the right regex to make it work so hoping someone with more regex exp can help me out.  I use VS Code as an IDE which should be able to handle regex find and replace.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris, please post what you have tried so far and what went wrong.

Comment: You may use something like `(assert\(\s*)'(.+)'(\s*\);)` and substitute with `$1$2$3`. Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/cFS6fT/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
(assert\(\s*)\'([^\']+)\'(\s*\);)
```

And replace it with

```
$1$2$3
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `[^\']` because there could be other single quote characters in the middle. I'd say `.` is better in this case.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I think the TS will adjust the regexp if there's a need.